# Integer upper bound to a subset of real numbers?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, real-numbers, predicate-logic, integers

Exploring the properties of real numbers from "[*Mathematical Thinking*](https://www.pearsonhighered.com/program/D-Angelo-Mathematical-Thinking-Problem-Solving-and-Proofs-2nd-Edition/PGM82529.html)" by John P. D'Angelo, I am asked to prove that

> For every positive real number $r$ there exists an integer $k$ such
>   that $5 \lt |k|r$

I would say that it is true by the Completeness Axiom, I think that this means "There exists an integer $k$ that is an upper bound to the set of real numbers of the form $\frac 5r$ where $r$ is a positive real number, which I would express as:

$$(\exists\,k \in \Bbb Z)\,(\forall \,r\in \Bbb R^+) \,:\, k=\,\sup \bigg\lbrace \frac 5r \bigg |\; r \in \Bbb R^+\bigg \rbrace$$

I'm not sure whether my reasoning is correct or how I would go about proving it though.

Comment: I believe the archimedian property of $\mathbb R$ will be useful here.

Comment: [This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/265384/archimedean-property-and-real-numbers) gives a formulation of it that I think might be useful.  Specifically, let $\epsilon = \frac{r}{5}$.

Comment: I dont think your reasoning makes any sense.  The set {5/r} is clearly unbounded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"I think that this means "There exists an integer k that is an upper bound to the set of real numbers of the form 5/r where r is a positive real number""

So that's obviously not true.  As $r \rightarrow 0$ then $5/r \rightarrow \infty$ and is not bounded above.

Consider this:  Let $A_r = \{|k|*r|k \in \mathbb Z\}$.  This is clearly not empty.  Are any of the $|k|r > 5$?  If not then $5$ is an upper bound of $A_r$ and $A_r$ is bounded above.  Is that possible?

If it were, let $a = \sup A_r$.  $r > 0$ so $a - r < a$ so $a-r$ is *not* an upper bound.  So there is a $|k|r$ so that $a - r < |k|r$ so $a < |k|r + r = (|k| + 1)r$ as $|k|+1 = ||k|+1|$ [*why in the world is this problem making a deal about absolute values... that's just confusing and irelevent*], we can conclude $(|k| + 1)r \in A_r$.

But that is a contradiction!  We have an element of $A_r$ that is *bigger* than it upper limit!  So $A_r$ is unbounded.  So it isn't bounded by $5$ (or anything else).

So it is not that case that all $|k|r \le 5$.  So some $|k|r > 5$.

---

This is the archimedian property that can be stated as.

For any $r > 0$ and any $y$.  There is some positive integer $k$ so that $kr > y$.

As  direct consequences we can say, for any $y$ there is an integer $k$ so that $k > y$.  Also that there is in integer $m$ so that $m \le y < m+1$. And for any $x < y$ there is a rational $q$ so that $x < q < y$.

Handy stuff to know.

Comment: That clarified things for me, thank you. I have a bad tendency to overcomplicate things for myself when questions seem suspectly simple. Also, I completely agree with you regarding the absolute value on $k$.

Answer (score 2):

You can prove this from the completeness axiom, but it's a bit tricky.  What you want to do is take the infimum of the set of reciprocals of counterexamples.  That is, take the set $$A=\{R\in\mathbb{R}^+:|k|/R\leq 5\text{ for all }k\in\mathbb{Z}\}.$$  This set is bounded below in $\mathbb{R}$, so if it is nonempty then it has an infimum $x$.  But if $R\in A$, then $R-1\in A$ as well (I'll leave proving that to you).  Since $x=\inf A$, there must be an element of $A$ that is less than $x+1$, and then subtracting $1$ gives another element of $A$ which is less than $x$.  This is a contradiction, which implies $A$ must be empty.