# Let $0<a<b<c<1$ be real numbers. Is this statement true?

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus

There always exists some constant k such that
$ b\geq \frac{a+c}{k} $?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

very strange wording. There is no **constant** bound that works for all such triples $a,b,c.$ take
$$ a = \frac{1}{n}, \; \; b = \frac{2}{n}, \; \; c = \frac{n-1}{n},  $$
$$ \frac{a+c}{b} = \frac{n}{2}  $$

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is equivalent to saying that
$$k \geq \frac{a+c}{b}$$
Since $\frac{a+c}{b}$ is some finite positive number, we can always find such a $k$ (and it must be positive).

Edit: I'm not sure if you are asking if $k$ is supposed to be universal i.e. the same $k$ can work for all $0 < a < b < c < 1$. If that's the case then we can't find such a $k$ since we can make $\frac{a+c}{b}$ arbitrarily large by letting $b$ (and hence $a$) become arbitrarily small.

Comment: Let $k=(a+c)/b.$

Answer (score 0):

Yes, and this is because the set of real numbers (or an ordered field with the Least Upper Bound property) has the [Archimedean Property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archimedean_property)

To put it more explicitly:

$$k(\frac{b}{a+c}) \ge 1$$

Then the Archimedean property guarantees a natural number $k$ exists.

[This post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/265384/archimedean-property-and-real-numbers) has more discussions about it.

Answer (score 0):

Well, even without the specified inequalities the statement is true, because of the Archimedian property of Real Numbers. If $x, y > 0$ then $\exists \ k\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $kx >y$. You can take $y= a+c$ and $x=b$ for your specific question.