# Proving the limit of a sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, epsilon-delta

I'm having trouble understanding how this works, conceptually.

Let's say I have the simple sequence $u_n = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$. I know that this converges to 0.

I wanna show that, no $\forall \varepsilon>0, \exists N\in \mathbb N$ s.t. $(n > N) \implies  \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} - 0 < \varepsilon$.

So in my head, to prove this for any example, I want to find a N defined as a function of $\varepsilon$. Is this the thought process I should be having?

Thus, I can just say that  $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} < \varepsilon \implies  \frac{1}\varepsilon< \sqrt n \implies \frac{1}{\varepsilon^2}< n $ (since $n$ and $\varepsilon$ are positive.)

And now, what? I think it's proven, right? If we just take $N = \frac{1}\varepsilon$, then the implication works every time? Do I have to show it by saying:

$\forall \varepsilon>0$, if $n > \frac{1}{\varepsilon^2}$, then we have $\frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{1}\varepsilon}}< \varepsilon \implies \frac{1}{\frac{1}\varepsilon} < \varepsilon \implies \varepsilon < \varepsilon $? But this isnt true,so where exactly am I going wrong? Thanks.

Comment: I tried to explain the through process [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/696574/another-epsilon-n-limit-proof-question/696665#696665). Your thought process is mostly correct, but you seem do to not have quite grasped it yet. You're close, though.

Comment: Choosing $N > \frac {1}{\epsilon^2},$ then for all $n>N, |\sqrt n | < \epsilon.$

Comment: You can't take $N=\dfrac{1}{\varepsilon^2}$ because $N$ must be a natural number. You do know, however, that there are natural numbers larger than $\dfrac{1}{\varepsilon^2}$. Let $N$ be one of those. I would now consider the work done as scratch work and start from the beginning.

Comment: You want to prove that $$\mathop{\forall}_{\varepsilon >0}\mathop{\exists}_{N\in \mathbb N}\mathop{\forall}_{n\in \mathbb N}\left(n>N\implies |u_n|<0\right).$$
Take $\varepsilon >0$ and let $N$ be a natural number larger than $\dfrac{1}{\varepsilon^2}$. Now take $n\in \mathbb N$ such that $n>N$. You can establish that $n>N>\dfrac{1}{\varepsilon^2}\implies \varepsilon>\dfrac{1}{\sqrt n}$ and that $n>N>\dfrac{1}{\varepsilon^2}$. The conclusion follows.

Comment: @GitGud Thanks a bunch! I didn't know you could simply describe $N$ as an inequality, but it makes complete sense. Also, the post you linked clarified a lot for me. Bouncing off of what that post was talking about, let's say i want to prove $|u_n| < \varepsilon$, and $u_n$ is an impossible difficult sequence to manipulate, but I know that it is bounded from above by 1 (obviously, if we know that it's bounded by 1, there'd be no point in finding the limit, but this is just a hypothetical to make sure I've understood this correctly), then I could simply say that $N > \varepsilon - 2$...

Comment: @GitGud ..., and I'd have proven the limit?  Sorry if that doesn't make sense. Also, another question, why did you feel the need to describe the sequences as functions in your other post? Is there some sort of benefit for this, or was this to make the idea clearer? Thanks again.

Comment: From bottom to top. I chose to use functions because of the intuitive concept "function of", in this case "$N$ as a function of $\varepsilon$", which you yourself used.

Comment: Regarding your example, I think you got it, but I'm not quite sure. If you were to use $\frac 1n$ instead of $1$ and maintain your argument, I'd say you understood it. Finally, regarding $N$, you need to prove its existence, it doesn't matter how you do it, as long as it's valid. One way to do it is using the [Archimedean Property](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/265384/archimedean-property-and-real-numbers) which is that I had in mind. But you can also construct $N$, $N:=\operatorname{int}\left(\dfrac{1}{\varepsilon ^2}\right)+1\color{grey}{\in \mathbb N}$.

Comment: @GitGud Now that I think of it, I'm having doubts as to whether or not I understand it too. What exactly do you mena by 'if you were to use $1/n$ instead of 1 and maintained your argument'? If I used the same argument for this problem, coud I just say that$ N > \varepsilon - 2 $works, since $1/n$ never goes above $1$, or am I confused?

Comment: @GitGud Oh! I just realized that $1/\varepsilon$ isn't always less than 2, so that wouldn't work, right?

Comment: Say $u_n$  is some complicated expression. In fact, let's use the example in the other thread I linked too. Say $u_n=\dfrac{n+2}{4n^2 + 2n}$, for all natural numbers $n$. You'll notice in my answer that I suggest you find a sequence $h$ such that $u<h$ and $h$ converges to $0$. A user found $h_n=\dfrac1{2n}$ which allows one to pick $N$ as any natural number greater than $\dfrac1{2\varepsilon}$. The rest is similar. Is this any help?

Comment: @GitGud I'm not understanding why $h$ has to converge to 0?

Comment: @GitGud Of course! Because $h$ must be less than $\varepsilon$ after a certain $N$ as well. Thanks a lot for the help and being patient enough to answer my dense questions!

Comment: Yes, that's correct. I do not think your questions are dense. Only geniuses sail through the details without hiccups. Most people avoid them.

Comment: @GitGud So is there some sort of method for finding a good sequence that's greater and converges to$0$? For example, what would your thought process be for a sequence like $2n+3/2n+1$? Would you find another easier-to-manipulate expression, or would you go about it differently?

Comment: I would definitely follow the same idea. Here you'll be considering $\left|\dfrac{2n+3}{2n+1}-1\right|<\varepsilon$ and sure enough, 

 $$\forall n\in \mathbb N\left(\left|\dfrac{2n+3}{2n+1}-1\right|\leq \dfrac 1n\right)_.$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that from here we have

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} < \varepsilon \implies  n>\frac{1}{\varepsilon^2}$$

then $\forall \varepsilon>0$ it suffices to choose $n>N>\frac{1}{\varepsilon^2}$ in order to fulfil the definition of limit.

Comment: Oops, stupid error on my part. But if I choose $N = \frac{1}{\varepsilon^2}$, then I would end up just getting $\varepsilon = \varepsilon$, right? Which is why you said that $N > \frac{1}{\varepsilon^2}$? So how do we remedy that?

Comment: @user494405 Yes we need $N>1/\varepsilon^2$ that is the first integer greater than $1/\varepsilon^2$ indeed in general $1/\varepsilon^2$ is not necessarly an integer. But those are really details!

Comment: Here's what I don't understand: I thought we had to define an N as a function of epsilon, and not give an inequality. So should I just say something like, $N = \frac{2}{\varepsilon^2}$? Since $\frac{2}{\varepsilon^2} > \frac{1}{\varepsilon^2}$?

Comment: @user494405 Yes, indeed note that in order to satisfy the definition of limit we can also take a larger value as $N=1000/\varepsilon^2$. Indeed we need just to show that this value exist such that for all $n > N \implies  \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} - 0 < \varepsilon$. It is not required by the definition to find the "optimal" value for N.

Comment: @user494405 The meaning of **$N$ as function of $\varepsilon$** is to be intended in the sense that we first fix $\varepsilon$ and then we can find an $N$ such that the condition is satisfied. That is we can't fix a value for $N$ that always work since if we fix $N$ first then we can find a value of $\varepsilon$ such that the condition is not satisfied. The rule of the game is first fix $\varepsilon$ then find $N$ such that...

Comment: I see, so can we really say that $N = 1000/{\varepsilon}^2? I thought that that didn't work, since N has to be a natural number? Thanks a bunch for the help.

Comment: @user494405 yes of course, sorry for the typo, I mean $N>1000/\varepsilon^2$

Answer (score 2):

> $  \frac{1}\varepsilon< \sqrt n \implies \frac{1}\varepsilon< n $

You appear to be assuming that $\sqrt \epsilon <\epsilon$. But when $\epsilon$<1, taking the square root makes it *larger*. So for $\epsilon<1$, you need $N>\frac{1}{\epsilon^2}$. If $\epsilon \geq 1$, then you can take N = 2. So you can take $N= max(2, \frac{1}{\epsilon^2})$

Comment: @Accumulation My apologies, I think I fixed it.

Comment: @Accumulation After re-reading this, I understand what you're saying. However, I don't understand what the benefit of saying $N > max(2, \frac{1}{\varepsilon^2})$ as opposed to $N > \frac{1}{\varepsilon^2}$. Is there one? Thanks.

Comment: @user494405 It's mainly a nitpicking thing. In this case, I guess it doesn't matter, but there are cases where one might find a formula for N in terms of $\epsilon$ that works for small $\epsilon$, but not large. The safe thing to do is to put a minimum value of N just in case something weird happens for large $\epsilon$.